# Checkbox array from custom post type in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a checkbox array for use in WordPress Advanced Custom Fields so that the user can select multiple values when he creates a post. The checkboxes should be created from another custom post type called Features (use field = "feature-name").

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: how many check box you required as custom field?

Comment: As many as there are custom posts of Features.